# Installing the same version of pyenv and boost_python

Tags: python, boost-python, pyenv

I have installed python by pyenv

```
$which python
/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/shims/python
$python -V 
Python 3.7.9
```

However in `/Users/whitebear/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9/lib/`,there is no `libboost_python**`

So I installed by brew `brew install python-boost`.

It is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar/boost-python3/1.75.0/`

However there is only `libboost_python39**` and `libboost_numpy39`

My python version is 3.7.9 though.

How can I install `boost_python` for `pyenv` the same version??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/585

You need to [build boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html) against the python version you installed in your pyenv

Comment: Thank you I use in `./bootstrap.sh --with-python-root=~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9` rewrite the `project-config.jam` `python : 2.7 : "~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9" ;` -> using `python : 2.7 : "~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.9" ;`  then exec `./b2`,`sudo ./b2 install`  successfully installed